# Problem with attaching a file with the .asm extension to a project in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86-64

I have a little problem, I'm writing an assembly function in x64 mode. Every time I have to write a function declaration (Extern "C" ...) in a .cpp source file it is a bit tiresome when the file already has a lot of lines. Is it possible to attach a file with the .asm extension to the project? Attaching .cpp or .h files works fine. The problem occurs when I want to add a .asm file (#include "sample.asm"). The strange thing is that something like this works (#include "sample2.h" or #include "samble3.cpp" ).

Every time I have to write a function declaration in a .cpp source file, but I would like to include the finished file ( #indluce "sample.asm") immediately, without having to declare it each time.

Of course, it uses microsoft visual studio

File source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "sample2.h" // it can be...
#include "sample3.cpp" // it can be..
#include "sample.asm" //causes an error 
using namespace std;

//extern "C" INT64 sum(INT64 a, INT64 b);  it always works

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

File sample.asm

```
.CODE


sum PROC

add rcx, rdx
mov rax, rcx

ret

sum  ENDP

END
```

Errors I get when sample.asm wants to attach. It is E0169- declaration was expected and C2059-
syntax error: "."

Comment: C2059 tells you it was a C-compiler error, not an assembler error, so the type must be set wrong and it's treating it as a C or C++ source file.  Wait, unless that's only from where you used `#include` to have the C preprocessor put the asm source text into your C++ program!!

Comment: Yes, my point is to add sample.asm to the project as you do with .h or .cpp files, so that you don't have to write a function declaration every time, but be able to call the function right away.

Comment: You can't, it's a different language.  Just like you couldn't include a Fortran function this way.  `#include` is just text processing, like you copy/pasted that .asm text into your .cpp.

Comment: (Well, I guess you could use *inline* assembly in a `naked` function so you can still write your own `ret` and so on.  But MSVC won't compile that for x86-64; you'd have to use clang-cl or regular clang with `-fasm-blocks`.  I wouldn't recommend inline asm until you already understand asm pretty well, and how C++ compiles to asm.)

Comment: @PeterCordes - maybe I misunderstood your comment bit MSVC doesn't allow inline asm with X64 builds. If the goal is to include statements like `extern "C" INT64 sum(INT64 a, INT64 b);`, then the OP should use a `.h` include file.

Comment: @rcgldr: That's exactly what I said.  MSVC doesn't allow inline asm for x64, so the only way to use inline asm is with a better compiler, like clang.  With clang-cl, you could probably even use MSVC-style `__declspec(naked) int64_t sum(int64_t a, int64_t b){ __asm { ... your code ... } }`, but of course you'd have to omit directives like `.code` and `PROC`; that's replaced by C++ syntax.

Comment: @PeterCordes - it wasn't clear to me the OP was asking about including extern statements or assembly code.